# OpenTBS/php problems with output

Tags: php, opentbs

I've writing a php application on a LAMP server that takes a document(.odt) and populates it with the right information in the appropriate spots. While the code compiles it presents me with a print out of the header on one page and a stream of apparent gibberish on the other as follows:

''mimetypeapplication/vnd.oasis.opendocument.textPK?H?1?ﾡҡThumbnails/thumbnail.pngﾉPNG  IHDR?g?ﾞﾡﾙIDATxﾜ?`??﾿?ﾧrҩ?Kﾖﾋ\䆻ﾱ ﾶ?l?R ﾤ )?ﾄﾄ?jﾨ&`lcﾊ{??ٲz??ﾖovg?6?ﾰ=yoovvv?3ﾯ?R0B#4tD~?ﾡ+ﾍF 5BCL#ﾐﾡ!ﾦHﾍ??ﾤFhﾈiR#4?ﾩbﾁ? 1ﾍ@jﾄﾆﾘF 5BCL#ﾐﾡ!ﾦHﾍ??ﾇﾔL?Dﾸă? ﾞ?BﾂD?~??HgﾤKﾂ PWﾟﾽﾛ?ﾵ?>oLR+?쟰.ﾾ?w???ﾶ8Q???ﾀ??8&ﾠ/ﾌ?Ć??a?8/Wﾨﾥ?,tﾥP[tﾱ캁?Is.!??.7?BN?ﾨ?0\ﾂ%ﾎ>? }?!4?ﾃ'0?5ﾸ?xLﾀ؀Eﾸ?x^?4?Gﾬﾈ#ﾞ??+`?<4ﾛ?ﾛﾰ<???ﾗz??ﾥﾛ?Dﾜxkﾞ??Fa'ﾌŜ -4ﾰg\ﾐ`6z^°??ﾤ?yﾩ

I suspect it might be an encoding issue and I've tried different approaches but so far nothing. I haven't had much luck looking for similar situations online so any suggestions/recommendations/help would be appreciated

```
<?php 

session_start(); 
include 'conn.php'; 

if(empty($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['password'])) 
    print("Access to database denied"); 
else { 
    $username = $_SESSION['username']; 
    $password = $_SESSION['password']; 
    $type = $_SESSION['type']; 

    if($type == "admin") { 
        include '../includes/aheader.html'; 
    } 
    if($type == "user") { 
        include '../includes/uheader.html'; 
    } 
    if(isset($_POST["searchButton"])) { 
        print_r($_POST);
        $keyword = $_POST['keyword']; 
        $choice = $_POST['choice'];

    if($choice == "company_name") 
        $sql = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE company_name LIKE ?"); 

    if($choice == "project_code") 
        $sql = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE project_code LIKE ?"); 

    $keyword = '%'.$keyword.'%'; 
    $sql -> bind_param('s', $keyword); 
    $sql -> execute(); 
    $result = $sql -> get_result(); 

        if(!$result) 
            print("<p>Select query failed</p>"); 
        else { 
            if($result -> num_rows == 0) 
            print("<p>No match found</p>");

        else {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $company_name = $row['0'];
                $phone = $row['1'];
                $address = $row['2'];
                $approximate_employees = $row['3'];
                $project_code = $row['4'];
                extract($row);
            }

            include_once('tbs_class.php');
            include_once('tbs_plugin_opentbs.php');

            $TBS = new clsTinyButStrong;
            $TBS -> Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN);

            $TBS -> LoadTemplate('document.odt');
            $TBS -> Show(OPENTBS_FILE, 'document.odt');             

            $TBS -> MergeField('company_name', $company_name);
            $TBS -> MergeField('address', $address);
            $TBS -> MergeField('phone', $phone);

        }
    }
}
    else {
        include '../includes/searchForm.html';
        include '../includes/footer.html';
    }
}
$mysqli -> close();
```

?>

Comment: Do you attempt to save the result of the merge in a new file or to send an HTML download ?

Comment: When prompted I've tried both saving the file or opening it directly. The results are the same.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. I've tried Show(OPEN_TBS_FILE) and it saves a document zip archive on the directory. Added a new file name and proper extension now its a proper file but the fields haven't been merged.

Comment: Some fields are now merging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to merge fields before to render the result.
And the result must be a file different from the template.

```
        $TBS = new clsTinyButStrong;
        $TBS -> Plugin(TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN);

        // Load the template
        $TBS -> LoadTemplate('document.odt');

        // Merge fields
        $TBS -> MergeField('company_name', $company_name);
        $TBS -> MergeField('address', $address);
        $TBS -> MergeField('phone', $phone);

        // Render the result
        $TBS -> Show(OPENTBS_FILE, 'document_result.odt');
```

Comment: I think the issue might be that the fields that aren't changing are within the body of paragraphs or not the first bit of text on a given line. Is there an additional plugin required for documents where some of the fields are embedded in a a body of text?

Comment: Header and footer are in a separated sub-file but not embedded text. Can you send to me a template that reproduce the problem ?

Comment: It's lengthy but you can see one of the fields that don't seem to change in the first few lines: [company.name]. I've tried onshow, onload and var but they produce no noticeable change

Comment: It seems like certain lines get skipped

Comment: Thanks for the pastebin but unfortunately it doesn't help to see what is going on in the inner XML source. Hav you seen this section of the documentation `b) Some TBS tags are not merged` at http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc#debug